# How to call function from renderless class React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Assume I have class A and B

```
class A extends Component{
    render() {
        return null;
    }

    foo = (a) => {
        return a;
    }
}

...


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(A);
```

And then call `foo()` at class B.

```
import A from 'path/to/A';

class B extends Component{
    let a;

    hey() {
        A.foo(a);
    }
}
```

And it gives me

`TypeError: _A.default is not a constructor`

I tried Almost everything.

1. Tried to call `new A().foo(a);` but not worked.
2. Tried to give static to funtion in A. like `static foo = () => ...` but in that case
   it can't see props of class A.(Class A props becomes undefined).
3. Tried to export class itself and export default on `connect()` seperately etc.

My question is, how can I use function of class A on class B. Consider I have redux on both classes. Class A is where business logic is located and on class B handles the UI.

Please don't close the question because none of Stackoverflow question solved my problem.
Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**

Assume my `foo()` function be like that with global state and dispatches.

```
foo = () => {
    let length = this.props.prod.length;
    let id = this.props.prod[length-1].id + 1;

    this.props.addProd({name: 'LOADING', id: id});
}
```

`this.props.prod` is from global state.
and `this.props.addProd()` is action creator which is working for push `prod` to global state.

If I would define this function without class. How can I call actionCreator or get global state in this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to make A a component you can export as simple as function and then call it in B:

```
export function foo(a) {
   return a;
}
```

then in B you call that function

```
import { foo } from 'path/to/A';

class B extends Component{
    let a;

    hey() {
        foo(a);
    }
}
```

if you need redux state in foo function you can pas as a parameter or I suggest to use redux-sagas .

Comment: I want to export function seperately but it gives error. Cannot export function inside the class.

Comment: You dont need class to export fuinction. remove class and just do like I did in file A put export funcion foo(a) {return a;}

Comment: But how can I handle lots of dispathes in that class? There are lots of dispatches and I am doing stuff based on global state.

Comment: I need more details to be able to understand what do you mean by lots of dispatches (please post your comonent).

Comment: I added the Edit section. Thank you for support

Comment: I am accepting your answer. I renewed my component structure about dispatches and global states. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A extends Component{
  render() {
      return null;
  }

  foo = (a) => {
      return <b>a</b>;
  }
}


class B extends Component{
  //let a;

  hey() {
      return new A().foo("a");
  }
  render() {
    return this.hey()
  }
}

var a = new A().foo("b")
console.log(a);
var b = new B().hey()
console.log(b);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <B/>
      <br />
      {new B().hey()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Using `<B/>` in jsx creates an instance.

If `<A/>` is exported as redux connected class - it can use redux.

Comment: In your code `hey()` function gives error because of `new A()`. Cannot create new object from class. it gives `_A.default is not a constructor`.

Comment: My classes is not at the same .js file. and I am using `connect()` on `export default`

Comment: If you need to use redux renderless then you don't need Component/react ... just google for `redux vanilla js`